# How do I get Eclipse with Android SDK running on Windows 8 to debug my app on my phone?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I can't imagine I'm the first person to have had this problem, yet stackoverflow did not recommend relevant questions. Sorry if it has been posted before.

I'm currently developing an android app, and I (laboriously) was able to get it working on Windows 8. I can run and debug my apps using the emulator, but I can't run them on my phone. My phone's version is 2.3.5 (api 10), I've installed the google usb drivers using the SDK manager, and I have the USB debugging setting checked off on my phone. I have been able to run my apps before when I loaded them from Windows 7. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: Phone is a Sprint HTC model number PC36100

Comment: Without knowing what brand or model of the phone, there's not much we can tell you about this. Some brands require their own drivers for connecting and developing on their devices. You say "I have the USB debugging setting checked off on my phone", does that mean it's not enabled? It should be.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Samsung phone and the Google USB Driver didn't work so I had to download and install Kies software (which has the driver for my Samsung phone) restarted windows and everything worked fine. I suggest you go to your phone manufacturer's site and download a proper driver. Good luck